# Prove that every number can be written in following form.

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $$\alpha>0 $$ Prove that every number x can be written in following from $$x=k\alpha +x_1$$ where k is an integer, and $0 \le x_1 < \alpha$.

I have tried using archimedianty by using the fact that every rational is between some consecutive integers,then I let k be negative or positive  one and let alpha be absolute x(this is for when x is rational).I am not sure if that works.If someone could supply proper proof or a hint I would be thankful

Reference: Spivak Calculus chapter 8 exercise 10

Comment: I presume you instead mean: "Let $\alpha > 0$. Then, for any $x$, there exists $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 \leq x_1 < \alpha$ such that $x=k\alpha + x_1$"

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: What can you say about the elements of $\{|k\alpha -x| : k \in \mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: That they are unbound?

Comment: Well, yes, but can you see why it has a minimal element?...

Comment: I did not see absolute value bar -.- .I understand what you mean.

Comment: No worries! Now that you have a minimal element, can you construct $x$ as required?

Comment: But you have constructed a set using x,how can I use it again to construct x?

Comment: The absolute value is actually going to make your life more difficult.

Comment: $x$ was always fixed in the first place! the numbers we want to find are the specific $k$ and $x_1$. And @DustanLevenstein: do you think so? Without absolute value I'd say it's less intuitive that there's an element that gives a 'least distance'; we can always subtract a multiple of $x$ if the element we pick is actually greater than $x$...

Comment: That's awfully convoluted.

Comment: Well at the expense of half a line's worth of justification, I don't think it's unreasonable at all. It's certainly much more intuitive/basic, which seems suitable. Feel free to write a less convoluted solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set $A=\{n\in\mathbb Z\mid n\alpha \le x\}$. It is bounded from above by $x/\alpha$, and is not empty (since $n\alpha\to-\infty$ when $n\to-\infty$, so for sufficiently large negative $n$, $n\alpha$ will be less than $x$).

A nonempty set of integers that is bounded above has a maximal element. Our $k$ is the maximal element of $A$.

Now let $x_1=x-\alpha k$. Since $k\in A$ we have $k\alpha\le x$ and so $x_1\ge 0$.

On the other hand, if $x_1\ge \alpha$ then $(k+1)\alpha\le x$, and thus $k+1$ would have been in $A$, contradicting the fact that $k$ was the maximal element in $A$.

Therefore $x=k\alpha+x_1$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $0\le x_1 <\alpha$.

---

*Exercise:* There's an appeal to Archimedes' axiom hidden somewhere in this argument. Find it!

---

If you know that every *real* $y$ is in $[k,k+1)$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, you can proceed a little quicker by setting $y=x/\alpha$ and getting $k$ from that.

Comment: Than you sooo much.

Answer (score 1):

Proof: Fix $\alpha = 2$ All integers are either even or odd: If this integer is even they take the form $k \alpha$ and if they are odd they take $k\alpha + 1$. 
We restrict $x_1 \in [0,1)$.

From this, any real number can be obtained by adding some $x_1$ to $k \alpha$ or $k\alpha +1$.

Clearly $\alpha> x_1\geq0$

Comment: I know that part,but what when x is rational and irrational?

Comment: @VanioBegic $x_1$ is required to be rational?

Comment: I have misread your post,I think I understand what you mean now.If you could furnish a full proof so I can be sure I would be thankful

Comment: you're assuming $\alpha=2$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein $\alpha$ is greater than $x_1$ will ever need to be, and is greater than 0

Comment: This does not seem right first you say $x_1$ is greater than 0 and then you say it belongs [-1,1].What is going on?

Comment: @VanioBegic Sorry, that was an error. Note revised $x_1 = [0,2)$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Can you take your downvote off now that you realize I am correct? -if you hadn't already I should say, and I mean no offense!

Comment: I realize no such thing. You're still claiming, e.g., with $x=5$ and $\alpha=3$, that $x=k\alpha+x_1$ has a solution with $x_1 = 0$ or $1$, when the truth is the only solution is $k=1, x_1=2$.

Comment: If you removed the first line and cleaned up your proof, I suppose it would technically be correct. I don't see how your hint is supposed to lead to a proof for general $\alpha$, though.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I don't understand what you are finding wrong with his proof. He has pinned $\alpha = 2$, which I believe is allowed by the question, and has stated that all integers can be constructed from $2k$ or $2k + 1$, which is true. He is then saying that $x_1$ can yield that required $+1$ and any decimal requirement without leaving the range of $x_1 = [0,2)$, which meets requirement $0 \leq x_1 \leq 2$ where $2$ is alpha, and $\alpha \gt 0$ since $\alpha = 2$. The question asks for all $x$ to be satisfied by that, and it is.

Comment: "All integers can be represented by $k \alpha$ or $k \alpha +1$, based on our understanding of integers, and modular arithmetic." With no mention of $\alpha=2$ to begin with here, the context suggests he is referring to the general problem posed, not to the special case, and in the general case, what he says is absolutely false. "$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},x = k \alpha + x_1$, where $k,\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$" Now he's restated the problem so as to allow himself to choose $\alpha$, without any note as to why he's doing this.

Comment: "$x_1 \subset ${1}$ \in \mathbb{R}$" is absolute garbage; it would at least be grammatical to say $x_1 \in \{1\} \subset \mathbb R$, so it's possible that that's what he meant to say, but still not clear what the insight he's going for there is, especially since he has not even defined $x_1$ yet. It looks like the proof would probably be okay if he just deleted that line, but we haven't heard from him since. Finally, if he wants to claim that $\alpha=2$ is assumed without loss of generality, and HINT that the original poster should try and prove this, he should say that explicitly!

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Oh my, what I had written was complete nonsense, sorry.

Comment: Oh hey, what a blast from the past! There's really nothing special about $\alpha=2$ here - you could just as easily have started with $\alpha=1$ and completely skipped the first step. And there should be a mention of the fact that $\alpha$ can be assumed to be your favorite number, 1, or 2, WLOG, if not a proof of the fact. Nevertheless, your exposition, sloppy though it might be, is no longer complete nonsense, so I'll go ahead and remove my downvote.